# .gitconfig not being generated in windows 7 machine

Tags: git

I have installed Git 2.15.1 64 bit on windows.
I then appended into 'PATH' system variable:
   `;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;`

Then I try to add git configuration by firing following commands on command promt:

```
cd c:\users\xxx
git config --global user.name "xxx"
git config --global user.email "xxx@domain.com"
git config --global credential.<url>.username xxx
```

Its expected that a c:\users\xxx.gitconfig file will be generated.
But no `.gitconfig` is generated, not even a hidden one.

I have observed that `git config --list` lists all the values that I just updated.
But on searching on my pc, I could not find any file/hidden file named .gitconfig with this data.
How may I overcome this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

to see where the global file it is. It is possible that your configuration (and HOME) is set in other places, e.g. for "roaming" or just for your local computer.

Comment: Thanks @Giacomo - this helped me figure all paths were being routed to network mapped home drive and this was because the Path envt variable had syntactical problems.